# Boto3 Cloudformation Drift Status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I'm trying to loop through every region and check if a stack has drifted or not, and then print a list of drifted stacks.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
import time

## Create a AWS Session
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default', region_name='us-east-1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## Connect to the EC2 Service
    client = session.client('ec2')

    ## Make a list of all the regions
    response = client.describe_regions()

    for region in response['Regions']:
        name = region['RegionName']

        print("Drifted CFn in region: " + name)
        ## Connect to the CFn service in the region
        cloudformationClient = boto3.client("cloudformation")
        stacks = cloudformationClient.describe_stacks()
        detection_id = cloudformationClient.detect_stack_drift(StackName=stacks)
        for stack in stacks['Stacks']:
            while True:
                time.sleep(3)
                # sleep between api calls to prevent lockout
                response = cloudformationClient.describe_stack_drift_detection_status(
                    StackDriftDetectionId=detection_id
                )
                if response['DetectionStatus'] == 'DETECTION_IN_PROGRESS':
                    continue
                else:
                    print("Stack" + stack + " has a drift status:" + response)
```

I am still new to Python and am unsure why it's failing on the StackName on line 22 when I know that the that's the name of the variable in "detect_stack_drift" that I'm trying to parse. Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

See these lines:

```py
stacks = cloudformationClient.describe_stacks()
detection_id = cloudformationClient.detect_stack_drift(StackName=stacks)
```

The `describe_stacks()` call returns:

```
{
    'Stacks': [
        {
            'StackId': 'string',
            'StackName': 'string',
            ...
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

However, the `detect_stack_drift()` function is expecting a single string in `StackName`.